# OpenGL in Visual studio - Issues with GLEW

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl, linker, glew

I'm currently following the openglbook.com tutorials ([set up](http://openglbook.com/setting-up-opengl-glew-and-freeglut-in-visual-c/)) ([Tutorial](http://openglbook.com/the-book/chapter-1-getting-started/)) and have run into an issue fairly early on. I'm getting the following two errors:

```
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glewGetErrorString@4 referenced in function _Initialize
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__glewInit@0 referenced in function _Initialize
```

I have downloaded and compiled freeglut 2.8.0 as well as the glew 1.9.0 binaries. I have copied the libs and includes to C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Lib and Include respectively.
The Lib and Include paths have also been added to my project properties under Additional Library/Include directories.

I have also defined glew32.lib and freeglut.lib in my linker->Input->Additional dependencies.

I have included GL/glew.h and GL/freeglut.h at the top of my main file.

What am I missing? Every other thread I've found has been solved by adding the directories to the project properties. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This means that you try to use GLEW as a DLL (because your application looks for a name that begins with __imp, like "import" ), but you didn't built GLEW as a DLL (because otherwise it would work).

3 possible options :

- Rebuild GLEW with the `GLEW_BUILD` preprocessor definition (Project->Properties->C++->Preprocessor->Additional definitions). Then rebuild your application.
- Don't build GLEW at all. Simply put glew.c in your application's project. This is the easiest way.
- (my favourite) Define `GLEW_STATIC` in your application's preprocessor definitions, and rebuild.

Comment: Thanks for that! I'll try those when I get home and mark the question as answered if it solves my problem :D